# Ajax form не работает.

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, form

Никак не могу решить проблему, всё перепробовал. На отдельном сайте работает, а тут нет. Что не так?

index.php

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{background-color: #FFFACD;}
            .welcome{
                background-color: #FAEBD7;
                border-width: 5px;
                border-style: ridge;
                border-color: #DEB887;
                padding: 7px;
                margin-left: 25px;
                margin-right: 25px;
                font-family: arial;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 20px;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="welcome"><center><p>Добро пожаловать, вы находитесь в калькуляторе уровня угрозы от [SASANDROWNA]</p></center></div>
        <br>
        <div class="tab">
            <form id="ajax_form">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Выберите уровень ожидаемой угрозы: </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="levelWarning">
                                <option value="null"></option>
                                <option value="3">Высокий</option>
                                <option value="2">Средний</option>
                                <option value="1">Низкий</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Выберите уровень отношений: </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="relations">
                                <option value="null"></option>
                                <option value="bad">Плохие</option>
                                <option value="medium">Средние</option>
                                <option value="normal">Нормальные</option>
                                <option value="best">Лучшие</option>
                                <option value="better">Наилучшие</option>
                                <option value="the_best">Отличные</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Выберите действие: <span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="action">
                                <option value="null"></option>
                                <option value="progul">Прогулял урок</option>
                                <option value="dva">Получил <b>2</b></option>
                                <option value="kurva">Спалился на курении</option>
                                <option value="kusokno">Разбил окно</option>
                                <option value="ogonok">Не пришел на огонек</option>
                                <option value="sapojnik">Матернулся при ЕА</option>
                                <option value="morewarn">Более опасное действие</option>
                                <option value="lesswarn">Менее опасное действие</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="button" id="btn" value="Отправить">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="result_form"></div>
    </body>
```

ajax.js

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(
  function(){
   sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form', 'action_ajax_form.php');
   return false; 
  }
 );
});
 
function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:     "post", //метод отправки
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
        success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
         result = $.parseJSON(response);
         $('#result_form').html('Ваш результат '+result.name+'<br>'+result.phonenumber);
     },
     error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
            $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
     });
  });
}
```

action_ajax_form.php

```
    <?php
$result = array(
        'name' => "alkash",
        'phonenumber' => "0"
    ); 
    // Переводим массив в JSON
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Есть какая-то ошибка в консоли?

Comment: `а тут нет. ` это где? Сходится мне, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к php скрипту не развернув локальный сервер, так?

Comment: Это на хостинге. Запускал чисто пример - работает, вставил в проект - не работает.